# Execute background code immedietly my app is completely terminated and never again

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

Am implementing the online/offline feature of my group voice call app. i want to remove the users from active users lift when they press the menu(to open all opened apps on device) and swipe away my app. So there i could fire a firebase function to remove. Right now i can handle only on willpop and when app is in background.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write that code in dispose method.

Comment: I have written the codes. They execute when the page is closed not when the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "**didChangeAppLifecycleState**"

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // add the observer
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // remove the observer
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    // These are the callbacks
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        // widget is resumed
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        // widget is inactive
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        // widget is paused
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        // widget is detached
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold();
}
```

Always Inactive the user on **AppLifecycleState.paused**
and Active the user again in **AppLifecycleState.resumed**

Comment: thank you samin. When my user takes the app in the background, is still active because can hear the sound/and can speak also using mic. Thats works perfectly. But i want to detect when while my is in background. The user clears all the apps from running. So as i can remove the user from active ones.

Comment: Then do it in AppLifecycleState.detached. Check the lifecycle as your own & determine where should you put the login.
It's hard to check if the app got killed by swipe away from recent screen of Killed by OS.
So Implement this, check what method is calling on what operation and code accordingly.